# How to add commission on PayPal user to user transaction with v2

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I am implementing PayPal user to user Transaction through my website and I need to take percentage fee from that transaction

I am using python paypalcheckoutsdk I know how to send money to a different user

```
from paypalcheckoutsdk.core import PayPalHttpClient, SandboxEnvironment
from paypalcheckoutsdk.orders import OrdersCreateRequest

environment = PayPalHttpClient(SandboxEnvironment(client_id=client_id, client_secret=client_secret))
paypal_request = OrdersCreateRequest()
paypal_request.prefer('return=representation')
payment_detail = {  
    "intent": "CAPTURE",
    "purchase_units": [
        {
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": "USD",
                "value": "80.00",
                
            },
            
            "payee": {"email_address": 'sb-i0it45775717@personal.example.com'},
        },

    ]
}
paypal_request.request_body(payment_detail)
response = environment.execute(paypal_request)
```

till now this can send money from one user to another user I want to implement a commission on the payee so that I get a percentage of every transaction that is made on my platform.

There are docs for v1 with adaptive payment but I can't find anything in v2.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything, platform fees are only available to approved PayPal partners.

If you want to apply, see https://www.paypal.com/bm/webapps/mpp/partner-program

Comment: can I test that in a sandbox environment?

Comment: You could create a sandbox partner app. Platform fees will not reflect in the sandbox interface, however. Only approved partners can test such features.